# understanding vtu file size

Tags: c++, linux, vtk

I am having a problem with understanding/managing sizes of .vtu files in VTK. I need to write CFD output for hexahedral meshes with millions of cells and nodes. So, I am looking at ways to improve the efficiency of storage. I started with simple test cases.

Case1: 80x40x40 hexahedral mesh with 8 points for each hexahedron. So, 128000 cells and 1024000 points in total. Let's call it C1.vtu.

Case2: 80x40x40 hexahedral mesh with only unique points. So, 128000 cells and 136161 points in total. Let's call it C2.vtu.

I store one vector field (velocity) for each point in each case. I use vtkFloatArray for this data. The size of C1.vtu is 7.5 MB, and C2.vtu file is 3.0MB.

This is not what I expected when I created C2.vtu. As I store only about 13% of points (of Case1) in Case2, I expected that C2.vtu would be reduced accordingly (at least 5 times). However, the reduction is only 2.5 times.

I would like to understand what is going on internally. Also, I appreciate any insights on reducing the file size further.

I am using vtk6.2 with C++ on Ubuntu12.04.

Comment: If you want to reduce size write binary files.

Comment: I do. The files reported above are already in binary format.

Comment: The file size is not proportional to the number of points, because the cells also need to be stored. For unstructured grids each cell can be of a different type, therefore connectivity and cell type information has to be stored. If your mesh is a structured grid, you can use vtkStructuredGrid, that should help you save some more space.

Comment: vtkStructuredGrid does not help my cause because my meshes will be unstructured. I used this simple structured mesh only for the purpose of understanding file sizes.
Unstructured grid stores cell connectivity for each cell. But, the number of cells and their connectivity information size is the same in both the cases. So, we expect that memory required for cells is same for both the cases. The only difference is the number of points and field data. No? My guess that there must be some internal optimisation going on when the files are compressed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have [compression enabled in the writer](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkXMLWriter.html); does `writer->GetCompressor()` return a non-NULL pointer? If so, then that is almost surely the reason for the difference in file sizes. Without compression, I would expect larger file sizes that you are reporting. As the comments above noted, unstructured storage adds connectivity overhead. Consider your meshes C1 and C2:

- C1

  - connectivity size = 128000 * (1 cell type + 1 cell offset + 8 point IDs) * (4 or 8 bytes per integer)
  - point coordinate size = 1024000 * (3 coords) * (4 or 8 bytes per coord)
  - vector field size = 1024000 * (3 components per tuple) * (4 or 8 bytes per component)
  - that would be 28.32 MiB at a minimum (all int32/float32) yet you report it is 7.5 MB
- C2

  - connectivity size = 128000 * (1 cell type + 1 cell offset + 8 point IDs) * (4 or 8 bytes per integer)
  - point coordinate size = 136161 * (3 coords) * (4 or 8 bytes per coord)
  - vector field size = 136161 * (3 components per tuple) * (4 or 8 bytes per component)
  - that would be 8 MiB at a minimum, but you report 3 MB.

Comment: Indeed. I already had the Zlib data compressor.ON. So, does it mean that I cannot get any further reductions in size?

Comment: Not much more compression without changing the representation you are using. As mentioned above, structured grids use less. You said your actual mesh was inherently unstructured, but without a real example there is no way to see whether you could do something like a structured grid with a blanking cell-array. Depending on the application, if the mesh is too big maybe you could use a coarser mesh? It's not like there's a lot of redundant information in the file, so how much compression were you expecting?

Comment: Using a coarse mesh is not in my hands. It is entirely up to the user of the software. I am the developer. My task is to optimise the output files for the ease of storing and post-processing. I have shared two typical meshes [here](https://ckadapa.wordpress.com/2017/08/04/vtk-files-fsi/)

Is there any VTK object that supports hierarchical meshes effectively?

Comment: See [this blog post](https://blog.kitware.com/visualization-analysis-of-amr-datasets/) for AMR data, which is what it looks like you are producing.